# Why is the peak transfer rate in memory module name always about 16 times the frequency used by the memory module?

Tags: memory

I have noticed that the peak transfer rate stated in RAM module names (*i.e.* PC3-10600) is always about 16 times the frequency used by those RAM modules.

Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A DDR3-1066 module actually runs at 533MHz. But it performs two transfers per clock cycle for an effective transfer rate of 1,066 million transfers per second. DDR3 modules have 64 data pins and transfer 64 bits in each transfer. 1066*64=68,266 Gb/s or 8,533 GB/s.

So it's 16 times the real clock speed because each transfer moves 8 bytes and transfers occur twice per clock cycle.